# SuperMicro server stuck at boot: 0xF1 "Recovery condition triggered by user (Forced recovery)"

Tags: boot, supermicro

I have a SuperMicro A1SAi-2550F that seems to be stuck at the boot screen, showing "Initializing..." and "F1". Per this doc (https://www.supermicro.com/manuals/other/AMI_BIOS_POST_Codes_for_Grantley_Motherboards.pdf) from SuperMicro, code 0xF1 means:

> Recovery condition triggered by user (Forced recovery)

What does this mean and how do I get past it?

Answer (score 0):

Hullo There!

The Recovery condition triggered status means that 
the motherboard waits for a recovery USB stick in one of the USB
2.0 slots.

I've had the same issue today, here is how I've resolved it:

1. Cleared all residue from the JBT1 Jumper (see A1SA i & A1SR i Series
   Motherboard Quick Reference Guide Rev. 1.1) with a q-tip and some
   isopropyl alcohol.
2. Removed all jumpers except JPG1 and JPL1, because the previous owner
   left a few jumpers in JI2C1/JI2C2.
3. Followed
   (https://www.supermicro.com/manuals/other/UEFI_BIOS_Recovery.pdf):
4. Downloaded the latest BIOS, renamed BIOS binaries to Super.ROM (case
   sensitive!) and moved the renamed file to a FAT32 USB stick.
5. Plugged the pendrive in a free USB 2.0 slot, and voile, the BIOS recovered.
6. I cleared the CMOS and loaded defaults upon the next boot.

I hope this helps mate.